# Активная activity в Android-приложении

Tags: android, java

Пишу первое Andorid-приложение. Возник такой вопрос: верно ли утверждение, что activity в Android-приложении всегда одна? Либо на весь экран, либо всплывающая, но **активная** activity все равно только одна?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы сказал не активная, а используемая в текущий момент(которая на верху стека активити) одна. На счет одной активити в приложении неверно. Их может быть хоть сотня.

Дополню. На самом деле у активити есть свой жизненный цикл. Она может быть запущенной, приостановленной, завершенной и т.д., но пользователь обычно взаимодействует только с одной. Советую почитать на эту тему [док](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)